# Invalid link to tag wiki history on Stack Apps

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, stackapps, default-tags

After going to this page:

https://stackapps.com/tags/bug/info

...I click 'excerpt history'. I am greeted with a 404 page (which is not a positive thing on Stack Apps - the 404 page, that is).

It seems like the target of the link is:

```
https://stackapps.com/posts//revisions
```

...which is obviously invalid.

Comment: I'll take your word for it rather than verify myself. (;

Comment: The general bug causing this was fixed in 2017: [404 error when attempting to view excerpt history of a tag on a per-site meta with a preset description that hasn't been edited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242167/404-error-when-attempting-to-view-excerpt-history-of-a-tag-on-a-per-site-meta-wi). This was tagged as completed because it was manually worked around for the one case mentioned here, but the general issue wasn't fixed until then.