# The tag wiki for [status-review] doesn't have a post id, leading to a 404 on viewing its history

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-wiki, revisions-list, default-tags

Behold, [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)'s [info page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/status-review/info):

[image]

Mousing over the `history` (or indeed the `excerpt history`) links shows the target URL:

```
meta.stackoverflow.com/posts//revisions
```

Following this, naturally enough, gives a 404.

I note the similar question [Invalid link to tag wiki history on StackApps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79126), but that now appears fixed *as if by magic* (ie with no answer having been given).

Comment: The actual issue here was fixed in 2017: [404 error when attempting to view excerpt history of a tag on a per-site meta with a preset description that hasn't been edited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242167/404-error-when-attempting-to-view-excerpt-history-of-a-tag-on-a-per-site-meta-wi). This post was tagged as completed because it was manually fixed for the one case, but the actual general bug wasn't fixed until then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Editing the tag-wiki has given the post a wiki entry.

Comment: Somebody's on a roll today!

Comment: Every day, @Pekka웃, every day.

Comment: weird, I didn't get notified about your comment. The only thing out of the ordinary is the comma after the 웃. Is this a bug?

Comment: @Pekka웃 - probably. It seems to have matched on it as well.