# Revision history links for wikis/excerpts for standard tags on metas (status-*, bug, discussion, etc) result in 404 error

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-wiki, per-site-meta, revisions-list

The history links for the "standard" tags that are present on all metas (the mandatory ones like [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and the mod-only ones like [featured](/questions/tagged/featured)) don't work unless the tag has been edited at least once since its auto-creation.

See, for example, the [bug](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/bug/info) tag on Meta.Anime.SE - the history and excerpt history links both go to https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/posts//revisions (which 404s), since I guess whatever process creates the wikis/excerpts for these tags doesn't actually assign them a post ID until they've been edited once.

It would probably make more sense for the wikis/excerpts for these "standard" tags to be assigned post IDs when they are created (I guess at site launch) so that they have a non-404ing revision history.

Note: this bug is only observable on child metas, but that's probably just because all the "standard" tags on Meta.SE have been edited at least once.

Comment: This issue appears to have been brought up [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168598/224428), but... that's not really a bugfix, unless Oded wants to go through and edit roughly 15-times-however-many-metas-there-are tag wikis

Comment: Yeah, I also [mentioned](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250039/256431) it on Meta.SO.

Comment: @MarkHurd: It looks like Adam Lear marked that request as completed in 2017. Per the answer there: "I pushed a change that disables the history links and adds a tooltip that explains that you're looking at the default initial revision and there's no other history to display in these cases." I guess this MSE post should have been tagged as [status-completed] as well – I've done so now.