# The imported tag-info for default tags is ignored in revision history

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, tag-wiki, revisions-list, default-tags

There are several [default tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62655/add-a-selection-of-default-tags-to-all-metas) which are automatically imported to all metas. (See also [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233898/what-tags-exist-by-default-on-child-metas).) It seems that some of them have been also imported with the tag-info. By looking at metas of some relatively new sites it seems that the tag-info was imported for

- [required tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/required-tags/info): discussion, support, feature-request, bug
- [moderator tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/moderator-tags/info): community-ads, status-completed, status-bydesign, etc.

It has already been reported that the link to revision history does not work for those tags: [Revision history links for wikis/excerpts for standard tags on metas (status-*, bug, discussion, etc) result in 404 error](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231527/revision-history-links-for-wikis-excerpts-for-standard-tags-on-metas-status)

I will add to the bug report linked above that if a tag info is edited then revision history is created. But it behaves as if the user who edited the tag actually created it. For example:

- [The tag info for discussion on Mathematics Educators Meta](https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/discussion/info) has been edited today, but the revision history says [it has been created today](https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/521/revisions). You can see in [Internet Archive](http://web.archive.org/web/%2A/https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/discussion/info) that it existed long before.
- I have made suggested edit to [the tag info for faq on Mathematics Educators Meta](https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/faq/info). I did not edit tag-excerpt only tag-wiki. Even though it was only one edit, it required two suggested edit reviews, both for [tag-excerpt](https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/11) (which I did not touch) and for [tag-wiki](https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/10). If you check the revision history, it also says that both tag-wiki and tag-excerpt have been created today.
- I have made suggested edit to the [tag info for faq on MathOverflow](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/faq/info). Situation is the same as above - I did not make any changes to the tag-excerpt, but there are two reviews, [one for tag-wiki](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/review/suggested-edits/248) and [one for tag-excerpt](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/review/suggested-edits/249). If you check the history, it says that the tag-info has been created two hours ago. In this specific instance it can be even checked in [Internet Archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20161024011952/https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/faq/info) that the tag-info existed long before my suggested edit. In addition to this, while suggested edit is pending, the tag-info appears to be empty. Again this can be seen from [Internet Archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20170111123332/https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/faq/info) - this capture was made while the suggested edit was pending. (When logged in, I saw the text with the usual: "This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed.")
- If a suggested edit is rejected, then the text is completely removed as can be seen from this experiment: Here is [a rejected edit to tag-info](https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/13). And you can see in the [capture from Internet Archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20170111165501/https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/support/info) that after the rejection the tag-wiki indeed appeared empty.

I will also add a link to [related discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34702148#34702148).

---

It is very likely that this problem and [404 error for revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231527/revision-history-links-for-wikis-excerpts-for-standard-tags-on-metas-status) have the same root cause. But I thought that it might be worth pointing out that apart from that, this also causes incorrect attribution of edits and suggested edits are shown incorrectly (in fact, non-existent edit suggestions are sometimes generated) and rejection of a suggested edit my result in removal of the text of the tag-info.