# The initial default version of the tag wiki excerpt is not shown on the tags page

Tags: bug, per-site-meta, tag-wiki-excerpt, tags-page

When looking at the tags on [Physics Meta](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/tags), I've noticed that many tags do not have the tag-excerpt. To my surprise, after I clicked on some of them I found out that they have a tag-info. (In fact, it is also displayed in the tooltip also on the tag-page.) When hovering over "history" link in the tag-info, I get a tooltip saying "This is the default initial version."

It seems that for some tags the tag-info is automatically created when a new meta site is created. (The only ones I found were the mandatory tags and moderator-only tags - see also: [The imported tag-info for default tags is ignored in revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289713).)

Is this behavior intentional? I think tag-excerpt for these tags should be displayed in the same way as the tag-excerpts for other tags are.

Here is a screenshot of what I see on [the tags page](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/tags):

[image: tags page - screenshot]

Here is what I see when I check [the tag-info for (discussion)](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/discussion/info):

[image: tag-info - screenshot]

And here is [the tag-info for (status-completed)](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/status-completed/info):

[image: tag-info - screenshot]

Comment: Reproduced partially on SFF & movies meta. The excerpt is showing up for discussion but not for bug, support and red tags.

Comment: @NogShine The likely explanation is that (discussion) no longer has the default version since it has been edited. Here is the revision history for [the tag-excerpt](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/10528/revisions) and for [the tag-wiki](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/10527/revisions).

Comment: Now, the question raises, why did those metas not get default tag wikis and someone had to add them?

Comment: @NogShine It is not clear to me what you mean in your last comment. I will just mention a known bug in tag-wiki/tag-excerpt history, in case this is what you meant: [The imported tag-info for default tags is ignored in revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289713).