# Change "http" to "https" in the tag-info imported for the default tags

Tags: feature-request, tag-wiki, per-site-meta, ssl, default-tags

On every per-site-meta, there are default tags<sup>1</sup> which are automatically created when the site is created. At the same time, the tag-info for some of them is created - although there are a few bugs related to these default tag-infos.<sup>2</sup>

I have noticed that some of those tag-wikis contain http rather than https link to various sites in the Stack Exchange network. For example, the site Bioacoustics is relatively new. If you look at the [tag-info for support](https://bioacoustics.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/support/info), the links to FAQ and search are both `http:`.

**Suggestion:** In the place from which these default tags are imported, change `http:` to `https:` where needed.

I will explicitly mention that this post is different from an older feature request: [Convert http links to https in tag wikis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300235). This post is about the text imported together with any default tag - the other one is about already existing tag-wikis.

---

<sup>1</sup>For more details, see [the tag-info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/default-tags/info) and this post: [What tags exist by default on child metas?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/233898)

<sup>2</sup>Such as: "[The initial default version of the tag wiki excerpt is not shown on the tags page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310794)" and "[The imported tag-info for default tags is ignored in revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289713)".

<sup>3</sup>The tag-wikis for default tags are actually not listed in SEDE - this is related to one of the bugs linked above. Still, searching for [tag-wikis containing https](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1599997/tag-wikis-containing-the-given-word-only-metas-networkwide?word=http:) on per-site-metas might at least help to give some impression which of the tags might be influenced by this.