# 404 error when attempting to view excerpt history of a tag on a per-site meta with a preset description that hasn't been edited

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-wiki, 404-not-found, default-tags

Any meta tag that have a preset definition (mainly the [moderator-tags](/questions/tagged/moderator-tags) and the [required-tags](/questions/tagged/required-tags), but there are possibly others that I don't know of, including maybe some that are not on metas) will take you to a nonexistent page like [`https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts//revisions`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts//revisions) when their tag wiki excerpt history is viewed.  For larger sites, this is generally not going to be found as the excerpts have all been edited, but smaller sites will experience this more often.  For example, [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) is broken right now on [Drones and Model Aircraft Meta](https://drones.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/discussion/info).  The issue goes away when the excerpt is edited.

This was prompted by my [meta SO post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274597/seems-like-the-status-review-meta-tag-has-a-broken-excerpt-history).

Answer (score 5):

This [was fixed in 2017](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/350725/1478931): the link has been completely removed from the about pages of tags that have the initial default version which hasn't been edited.

Attempting to click on the history links on such tags no longer does anything, and hovering over the link shows a tooltip that it's the initial default version:

[image: This is the default initial version.]

Therefore, since the broken links are no longer shown, I'd call this [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Comment: Yep. Specifically, this was addressed by [Adam Lear's response in 2017 to a report of the same bug on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/350725/1478931): "I pushed a change that disables the history links and adds a tooltip that explains that you're looking at the default initial revision and there's no other history to display in these cases."