# Should this site have a tag for "default tags"?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, meta, default-tags

When a new Stack Exchange site is created, some tags are automatically created on its corresponding meta site. (I don't think there are any such tags on the main/regular Stack Exchange site itself.) These tags seemingly aren't deleted even if they remain unused. Tags in this category seem to include mod-only tags, such as [featured](/questions/tagged/featured), and required tags, such as [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) – as well as some ordinary tags like [bounty](/questions/tagged/bounty), [users](/questions/tagged/users), and [rss](/questions/tagged/rss).

I was recently searching MSE bug reports/feature requests related to this feature, but wasn't sure what to search for. I tried searching for `default tags`, but it was still tricky to sort out the relevant results from the rest.

There are multiple posts here on MSE about this feature:

- [What tags exist by default on child metas?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/233898/335251)
- [The [interesting-tags] tag should not be a default tag on Meta sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310392/335251)
- [Please remove some redundant tags from the list of default tags on child metas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234473/335251)
- [Add a selection of default tags to all metas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/62655/335251)
- [404 error when attempting to view excerpt history of a tag on a per-site meta with a preset description that hasn't been edited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/242167/335251)
- [Revision history links for wikis/excerpts for standard tags on metas (status-*, bug, discussion, etc) result in 404 error](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231527/335251)
- [The imported tag-info for default tags is ignored in revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289713/335251)

...and probably a few others linked from those ones (e.g. [The tag wiki for [status-review] doesn't have a post id, leading to a 404 on viewing its history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168598/335251) and [Invalid link to tag wiki history on StackApps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79126/335251)) about issues related to specific default tags.

Given the difficulty I had in finding these sorts of questions about a single shared topic, it seems to make sense to create a tag for that topic.

**Should this site have a tag for posts (feature requests, bug reports, support questions, etc.) about these "default tags"?** If so, what should it be called – [default-tags](/questions/tagged/default-tags), or something else?

(I'm not sure if the feature has an official name, but "default tags" seems to at least be what the community tends to call them, and it makes sense to me as well.)

---

Note: I'm not asking in my capacity as a CM, just as a user.

Comment: Related on [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/350725)

Comment: I like this idea a lot; tags are designed to make posts on a given topic easier to find by labeling and ["*sorting \[them\] into specific, well-defined categories*"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/tagging), this seems like the perfect occasion for a new tag.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are 3 choices as I see them:

1. Create a separate tag as you propose.
2. Just mention it in the tag-wiki for [tags](/questions/tagged/tags).
3. Create a canonical post introducing and explaining the feature.

I think creating a separate tag on MSE is the optimal choice because it's the better alternative to surface this meta-wide feature. Currently searching for the term "tags" [in the tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags) gives 36 hits which seems to group specific tag functionalities that are comparable.

Also note that textually searching for "default tags" will give hits that aren't about the specific feature, for example [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/314471).

> Should this site have a tag for posts (feature requests, bug reports, support questions, etc.) about these "default tags"?

There's already the [meta-tags](/questions/tagged/meta-tags) but it's is too broad to surface this specific feature.

> If so, what should it be called – [default-tags](/questions/tagged/default-tags), or something else?

I think that's a good choice of name that follows the prevalent naming conventions for *tags containing "tags"*.

Comment: meta-tags could mean, well tags that are meta in nature ...

Comment: I've gone ahead and created the [default-tags] tag now, and added it to (most of) the questions I linked above.

Answer (score 4):

[meta-default-tags](/questions/tagged/meta-default-tags) might work here. It avoids the 'confusion' of calling them meta tags, roughly follows the naming convention we'd use, and reflects what they are. Needs to be paired with a good tag wiki excerpt and wiki of course.